# if statement with currenturl in twig/slim3

Tags: if-statement, twig, slim

I have a problem  which might be simple but I can't figure it out :)

I have a slim 3 / twig app and have made an global variable so I can get the currentUrl in twig.

In a template-file I wan't an if statement checking if the currentUrl contains the string '/forretter' so it only show these products in an for loop.

If I do an simple `{{ currentUrl }}` it prints the url as expected - but the if statement doesn't seem to accept the currentUrl variable.

I have tried to do an `{% set url = currentUrl %}` but no luck.

The if statement I am using looks like this `{% if '/forretter' in currentUrl   %}` all other if statements I set up works like a charm.

home someone has an idea about this cause I beginning to get grey hair on my bald head :)

I have now tried Georgy Ivanov answer and tried to match it to my code - and the twig extension works - but the if statement doesn't.

Here is my container code

```
<?php

use function DI\get;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Cart\Basket\Basket;
use Cart\Models\Product;
use Cart\Models\Edit;
use Cart\Models\Order;
use Cart\Models\Customer;
use Cart\Models\Address;
use Cart\Models\Payment;
use Slim\Views\TwigExtension;
use Slim\Views\IsInUrlExtension;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Cart\Support\Storage\SessionStorage;
use Cart\Support\Storage\Contracts\StorageInterface;
use Cart\Validation\Contracts\ValidatorInterface;
use Cart\Validation\Validator;

return [
    'router' => get(Slim\Router::class),
    ValidatorInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Validator;
    },
    StorageInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new SessionStorage('cart');
    },

    Twig::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        $twig = new Twig(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', [
          'debug' => true,
          'cache' => false,
        ]);

        $basePath = rtrim(str_ireplace('index.php', '', $c->get('request')->getUri()->getBasePath()), '/');
    // Add Slim specific extension
        $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
        $twig->addExtension(new TwigExtension(
            $c->get('router'), $basePath,
            $c->get('request')->getUri()
        ));
        $twig->addExtension(new IsInUrlExtension($c->get('request')->getUri()));
        $twig->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('currentUrl',$c->get('request')->getUri());
        $twig->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('basket', $c->get(Basket::class));

        return $twig;
    },

    Product::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Product;
    },

    Edit::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Edit;
    },

    Order::class=> function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Order;
    },

    Customer::class=> function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Customer;
    },

    Address::class=> function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Address;
    },

    Payment::class=> function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Payment;
    },

    Basket::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new Basket(
            $c->get(SessionStorage::class),
            $c->get(Product::class)
        );
    }
];
```

And here is the twig code with the if statement

```
{% extends 'templates/app.twig' %}

{% block navigation %}
  {% include 'templates/partials/navigation.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row p__top">
  {% include 'templates/partials/sidebar_left.twig'  %}
  <section class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="product">

      {% if is_in_url('/forretter') %}

        <div class="row">
          <div class="categori__image">
            <img class="card-img-top"  src="{{site_url}}/images/varmrogetlaks.jpg" alt="Forretter">
          </div>
          <header class="menu__block">
            <h3 class="menu__title">Forretter</h3>
          </header>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <div class="card-deck">
              {% include 'products/dinertransportable/partials/produkter.twig' %}

            </div>
        </div>

      {% else %}
        test2
      {{ dump(currentUrl) }}

      {% endif %}


    </div>
  </section>
  {% include 'templates/partials/sidebar_right.twig'  %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you give an example url like ``currentUrl``?

Comment: How did you make the `global variable` in twig please? Can you edit your post and show more of the code you tried? I think this should be easy to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Twig extension, something like this:

```
<?php
class IsInUrlExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function __construct($currentUrl)
    {
        $this->currentUrl;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'extName';
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('is_in_url', [$this, 'isInUrl']);
        ];
    }

    public function isInUrl(string $substr) : bool
    {
        return strpos($this->currentUrl, $substr) !== false;
    }
}
```

Add this extension when you're registering Twig component in your container:

```
// Register component on container
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('path/to/templates', [
        'cache' => 'path/to/cache'
    ]);

    // Instantiate
    $basePath = rtrim(str_ireplace('index.php', '', $container['request']->getUri()->getBasePath()), '/');
    // Add Slim specific extension
    $view->addExtension(new Slim\Views\TwigExtension($container['router'], $basePath));
    // Add your extension
    $view->addExtension(new IsInUrlExtension($container->get('request')->getUri()));

    return $view;
};
```

Then you could use it within your templates like this:

```
{% if is_in_url('/forreter') %}
// substring is in current URL
{% endif %}
```

The benefit of this method is that you don't have to declare global `currentUrl` variable in your templates, and this `strpos` logic is not implemented in your templates, or, rather, it is encapsulated in your *reusable* extension.